# joblib results vary wildly depending on return value

Tags: python, spacy, joblib

I have to analyse a large text dataset using Spacy. the dataset contains about 120000 records with a typical text length of about 1000 words. Lemmatizing the text takes quite some time so I looked for methods to reduce that time. [This arcicle](https://prrao87.github.io/blog/spacy/nlp/performance/2020/05/02/spacy-multiprocess.html) describes how to speed up the computations using joblib. That works reasonably well: 16 cores reduce the CPU time with a factor of 10, the hyperthreads reduce it with an extra 7%.

Recently I realized that I wanted to compute similarities between docs and probably more analyses with docs later on. So I decided to generate a Spacy document instance (<class 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc'>) for all documents and use that for analyses (lemmatizing, vectorizing, and probably more) later on. This is where the trouble started.

The analyses of the parallel lemmatizer take place in the function below:

```
def lemmatize_pipe(doc):
    lemma_list = [str(tok.lemma_).lower() for tok in doc
                  if tok.is_alpha]

    return lemma_list
```

(the full demo code can be found at the end of the post). All I have to do is returning `doc` instead of `lemma_list` and I'm ready. I thought.

```
def lemmatize_pipe(doc):

    return doc
```

The sequential version runs in 73 seconds, the parallel version returning `lemma_list` takes 7 seconds while the version returning `doc` runs in 127 seconds: twice as much as the sequential version. Full code below.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import gensim.downloader as api
import spacy

from pdb import set_trace as breakpoint

# Initialize spacy with the small english language model
nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['parser', 'ner', 'tagger'])
nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('sentencizer'))

# Import the dataset and get the text
dataset = api.load("text8")
data = [d for d in dataset]
doc_requested = False

print(len(data), 'documents in original data')

df_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['content'])
df_data['content'] = df_data['content'].astype(str)

# Content is a list of words, convert is to strings
for doc in data:
    sentence = ' '.join([word for word in doc])
    df_data.loc[len(df_data)] = [sentence]

### === Sequential processing ===
def lemmatize(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    lemma_list = [str(tok.lemma_).lower() for tok in doc
                  if tok.is_alpha]

    return doc if doc_requested else lemma_list

cpu = time.time()

df_data['sequential'] = df_data['content'].apply(lemmatize)
print('\nSequential processing in {:.0f} seconds'.format(time.time() - cpu))
df_data.head(3)

### === Parallel processing ===
def lemmatize_pipe(doc):
    lemma_list = [str(tok.lemma_).lower() for tok in doc
                  if tok.is_alpha]

    return doc if doc_requested else lemma_list

def chunker(iterable, total_length, chunksize):
    return (iterable[pos: pos + chunksize] for pos in range(0, total_length,
                                                           chunksize))
def process_chunk(texts):
    preproc_pipe = []
    for doc in nlp.pipe(texts, batch_size=20):
        preproc_pipe.append(lemmatize_pipe(doc))

    return preproc_pipe

def preprocess_parallel(data, chunksize):
    executor = Parallel(n_jobs=31, backend='multiprocessing', prefer="processes")
    do = delayed(process_chunk)
    tasks = (do(chunk) for chunk in chunker(data, len(data), chunksize=chunksize))
    result = executor(tasks)
    flattened = [item for sublist in result for item in sublist]

    return flattened

cpu = time.time()
df_data['parallel'] = preprocess_parallel(df_data['content'], chunksize=1)
print('\nParallel processing in {:.0f} seconds'.format(time.time() - cpu))
```

I have searched and tried all kind of things but could not find a solution. In the end I have decided to compute the similarities together with the lemma's, but that is a workaround. What actually is the cause of the time increase? And is there a way to get the docs without losing that much time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pickled `doc` is quite large and contains a lot of data that isn't needed to reconstruct the doc itself, including the entire model vocab. Using `doc.to_bytes()` will be a major improvement, and you can improve it a bit more by using `exclude` to exclude data that you don't need, like `doc.tensor`:

```py
data = doc.to_bytes(exclude=["tensor"])
...
reloaded_doc = Doc(nlp.vocab)
reloaded_doc.from_bytes(data)
```

To compare:

```py
doc = nlp("test")
len(pickle.dumps(doc))                              # 1749721
len(pickle.dumps(doc.to_bytes()))                   # 750
len(pickle.dumps(doc.to_bytes(exclude=["tensor"]))) # 316
```

You can also use `doc.to_array()` instead of `doc.to_bytes()` to export only the annotation layers that you need, but reloading the doc from the array is slightly more complicated.

See:

- https://spacy.io/usage/saving-loading#docs
- https://spacy.io/api/doc#serialization-fields

Comment: It had never occurred to me to look for the pickle size, explains a lot. Thanks a lot for your explanation and especially for the links.